# AngularJS select options in an input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in an AngularJS template:

```
<input
    type="number"
    id="exercise-log-duration-hours-{{ ::$id }}"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="$ctrl.workoutHours"
    ng-change="$ctrl.updateHours($ctrl.workoutHours)"
    name="{{ ::$ctrl.inputName }}"
    step="1"
    min="1"
    required> 
  </input>
```

I want to give the user a dropdown with the options:

```
ctrl.hourOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

From the corresponding component file.

I had intended to use ui-select but that does not appear to be an option because I need to leave the user with the ability to enter a number not in the options list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a combination of the HTML [`<select>` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element and the AngularJS directive [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to create the options from the list in addition to an `"other"` option that will produce an input box ([Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOxoNP)):

```
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="ExampleController as $ctrl">
  <select id="exercise-log-duration-hours-{{ ::$id }}"
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="$ctrl.workoutHours">
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    <option ng-repeat="hour in $ctrl.hourOptions" value="{{hour}}">{{hour}}</option>
  </select>
  <div ng-if="$ctrl.workoutHours === 'other'">
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" ng-model="$ctrl.workoutHoursOther" />
  </div>
  <p>Selected: {{$ctrl.workoutHours}}</p>
</div>
```

So before your form submits you'll want to check to see if the value of `workoutHours` is equal to `'other'` and if so, submit the value bound to `workoutHoursOther` instead.